# Retriving a setting in a Web.Config <configSections>

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have this code in my Web.Config file:

```
   <configSections>
        <section name="myWebAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
    </configSections>
    <myWebAppSettings isTestEnvironment="true"/>
```

I need retrieve my value `isTestEviroment` from `Global.asax`

At the moment I use with no sucess:

```
bool isTestEnvironment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues["isTestEnvironment"];
```

What I'm doing wrong here?
NOTES: I do not assume my Web.Config file is right so please feel free to change it if I did not written correctly. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: In which method you are trying to read settings? (Session Start, App Start)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` retrieves values from the `AppSettings` configuration element, not your custom section.

You need to use:

```
var section = (HashTable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myWebAppSettings");
bool isTest = Boolean.Parse(section["isTestEnvironment"].ToString());
```

Comment: I m trying this section.GetType(isTestEnvironment) == "0" no success. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: @GibboK - Answer updated. `GetType` will just get the type of the attribute, not a value.

Comment: thanks Oded I apreciate your help, now is working fine. Please update your code with a ToString() like this so the debugger doe not comlain :-)....             var section = (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myWebAppSettings");
            bool isTest = Boolean.Parse(section["isTestEnvironment"].ToString());